# Change selected item in ListBox (Matlab App Designer)

Tags: matlab, user-interface, signal-processing, matlab-app-designer

for a uni project, I have to create a GUI that processes EEG data. The data has already been processed by me but for the GUI we're supposed to work with unprocessed data. I'm working with three scenarios called 'Paradigma' in my code. [current GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8CW6.png) I load the data of three different workspaces and assign them to each item in the ListBox seen on the right.

```
        % Button pushed function: loadDataButton
        function loadDataButtonPushed(app, event)
            app.ws1 = load('App/app_p1.mat');
            app.zeit = app.ws1.eeg_1;
            app.t = app.ws1.t_1;
            app.freq = app.ws1.EEG_1;
            app.f = app.ws1.f_1;
            app.F = app.ws1.F;

            app.ws2 = load('App/app_p2.mat');
            app.zeit = app.ws2.eeg_2;
            app.t = app.ws2.t_2;
            app.freq = app.ws2.EEG_2;
            app.f = app.ws2.f_2;
            app.F = app.ws2.F;

            app.ws3 = load('App/app_p3.mat');
            app.zeit = app.ws3.eeg_3;
            app.t = app.ws3.t_3;
            app.freq = app.ws3.EEG_3;
            app.f = app.ws3.f_3;
            app.F = app.ws3.F;
            
        end
```

```
  function ParadigmaAuswahlListBoxValueChanged(app, event)
            
            value = app.ParadigmaAuswahlListBox.Value;
            
            switch value
            case 'Paradigma 1'
            app.ws1;
            case 'Paradigma 2'
            app.ws2;
            case 'Paradigma 3'
            app.ws3;
            end

            
        end
```

Plotting the data works fine but I can't change the selected Paradigma from the ListBox once I've started working with any of the other. Unless I close and reopen the App of course.

I thought about adding the Button "neues Paradigma", that, if pressed "resets" the selections I've made. But so far I've only been able to clear the UIAxes.
I don't really know what I'm doing so help would be appreciated.
I also tried to add this at the end of the ParadigmaAuswahlListBox Function:
`app.ParadigmaAuswahlListBox.Value = {}`  but that obviously wouldn't work.

Comment: It is not clear what you actually want to do. If you want to remove all the item listed in the listbox, you can set `app.ParadigmaAuswahlListBox.Items={}`
This can be inserted, for example, in the callback of the "neues Paradigma" pushbutton.

Comment: If you want to change the data to work with following the selection of a different item between the one already in listbox, you can add a property, say, `current_ws` to the app, then, in the  switch of the `ParadigmaAuswahlListBoxValueChanged` callback you can assign the selected `ws` to `current_ws`. After that, you can use `current_ws` in any other function or callback of the app since it will contain the selected data